# Can't scroll to things added to canvas by a button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm finishing building an app managing a JSON and while everything is scrolling when it's added before the mainloop starts, if I add it by a button, I can't scroll to the newly added things (I add them by canvas.create_window(0, getfirstfreeposition(), window=thing)). I have the grid weights set up to 1 on my Toplevel and Tk windows and "Configure"=lambda event:canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all") on all canvases.

Edit: after a bit of research, reopening Toplevel window lest me scroll properly

Edit 2: link to repo with code: https://github.com/Gutek8134/AID-state-creator

Comment: Do you configure the `scrollregion` whenever you add items to the canvas? Just binding to the `<Configure>` event won't do it since that event doesn't fire when you add items to the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley I do not. Can you give me some more info? I'm commenting the code rn, so I can try it in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reconfigure the `scrollregion` for the canvas whenever things are added to or removed from the canvas. It can be as simple as doing this after adding one or more items to the canvas:

```
the_canvas.configure(scrollregion=the_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: I've just added line under every create_window and the problem seems to be fixed. Great thanks.